# Converting CAML to SPQuery syntax

Tags: 2010, development

Following CAML Query is giving me all the events for the upcoming two weeks.
Does anyone have an idea how to convert the part [Today+14Day(s)] correctly when using the 
SPQuery class syntax to use the query in my code behind visual web part (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx)

<'Query>
   <'Where>
      <'And>
         <'Lt>
            <'FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <'Value Type='DateTime'>[Today+14Day(s)]<'/Value>
         <'/Lt>
         <'Geq>
            <'FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <'Value Type='DateTime'>[Today]
         <'/Geq>
      <'/And>
   <'/Where>
<'/Query>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is either easy to answer, or I have completely misunderstood what you are asking, so here goes:

In your code-behind, where you are creating the CAML query string, you will need to programmatically construct the date. Something like:

```
string query = "<query> ...... <Value type='DateTime'>" + DateTime.Today.AddDays(14).ToString("O") + "</Value> .... </query>";
```